# Tensorflow train data generator flow problem

Tags: tensorflow

I'm confused about the following shape problem. my input image is grayscale image, so choose 1 as X value(according to train.DataGen.flow rules in TensorFlow) but I get the following error.

```
AxisError: axis 3 is out of bounds for array of dimension
```

`
The code is as following.

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: train_val_generators
def train_val_generators(training_images, training_labels, validation_images, validation_labels):
  ### START CODE HERE

  # In this section you will have to add another dimension to the data
  # So, for example, if your array is (10000, 28, 28)
  # You will need to make it (10000, 28, 28, 1)
  # Hint: np.expand_dims
  training_images = np.expand_dims(training_images,axis=3)
  training_labels=np.expand_dims(training_labels,axis=3)
  validation_images = np.expand_dims(validation_images,axis=3)
  validation_labels=np.expand_dims(validation_labels,axis=3)

  # Instantiate the ImageDataGenerator class 
  # Don't forget to normalize pixel values 
  # and set arguments to augment the images (if desired)
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest'
  )


  # Pass in the appropriate arguments to the flow method
  train_generator = train_datagen.flow(x=training_images,
                                       y=training_labels,
                                       batch_size=32) 

  
  # Instantiate the ImageDataGenerator class (don't forget to set the rescale argument)
  # Remember that validation data should not be augmented
  validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      resclae=1./255
  )

  # Pass in the appropriate arguments to the flow method
  validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow(x=validation_images,
                                                 y=validation_labels,
                                                 batch_size=32) 

  ### END CODE HERE

  return train_generator, validation_generator
```

for x value, I have used 3 for RGV Value, but another error Appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/a7madmostafa/sign-mnist-with-cnn-100-accuracy/data) dataset to reproduce the issue.

In the above code you are trying to expand the dimensions of the labels like this:

```
training_labels=np.expand_dims(training_labels,axis=3)
validation_labels=np.expand_dims(validation_labels,axis=3)
```

Removing these lines will solve the error.
Please find the working code below.

```
def train_val_generators(training_images, training_labels, validation_images, validation_labels):
  
  training_images = np.expand_dims(training_images,axis=3)
  #training_labels=np.expand_dims(training_labels,axis=3)
  validation_images = np.expand_dims(validation_images,axis=3)
  #validation_labels=np.expand_dims(validation_labels,axis=3)
  image_gen= ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,)
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=40,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest'
  )

  val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,)
  
  train_generator = train_datagen.flow(x=training_images,
                                       y=training_labels,
                                       batch_size=32)

  validation_generator = val_datagen.flow(x=validation_images,
                                       y=validation_labels,
                                       batch_size=32) 

  return train_generator, validation_generator
```

Let us know if the issue still persists.Thanks!